# one to many relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a one to many relationship, when I try to save it, it asks me to enter the FK should not I do it automatically?

```
class AlternativesCompetitorsImage extends Model
{
    public function alternativecompetitors()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AlternativesCompetitor::class,'id');
    }
}



class AlternativesCompetitor extends Model
{

    public function alternativescompetitorsimages(){
        return $this->hasMany(AlternativesCompetitorsImage::class,'alter_comp_id');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
$ci = isset($id_image) ? $step->alternativescompetitorsimages :  new AlternativesCompetitorsImage();

        if( $request->hasFile('fileImg')){
            $fileRequests = request()->file('fileImg');
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($fileRequests as $fileRequest) {
            $keyCanvas = $c->key;
            $stepKey = $stepType->key;
            $public= public_path();
            $directory =DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."canvas".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$keyCanvas.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$stepKey;
            $newName = "image".$count.".png";
            Storage::deleteDirectory($directory);
            $path = $fileRequest->storeAs("public".$directory,$newName);
            $str = str_replace("\\", '/', $path);
            $ci->url_img = $str;
             !isset($id_image) ? $step->alternativescompetitorsimages()->save($ci) : $step->alternativescompetitorsimages()->update($ci->toArray());           
            DB::commit();
            $count++;
            }
```

Migrations

```
class CreateAlternativesCompetitorsImages extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('alternatives_competitors_images',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('url_img',100);
            $table->integer('alter_comp_id')->unsigned();            
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('alter_comp_id')->references('id')->on('alternatives_competitors');
            });
    }


class CreateAlternativesCompetitors extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('alternatives_competitors',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('step_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('valueA',10);
            $table->string('valueB',10);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('step_id')->references('id')->on('steps');
            });
    }
```

> Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'alter_comp_id' cannot be null (SQL:
>   insert into `alternatives_competitors_images` (`url_img`,
>   `alter_comp_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (public/canvas/de939a01-1438-4aff-bb23-eb4f68653f5f/TEAM/image0.png, ,
>   2018-03-27 23:31:12, 2018-03-27 23:31:12)) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\canvas\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:647

Comment: reorder the migration file, first `alternatives_competitors` then the other one

Comment: in that order they are

Comment: do you have any records in `alternatives_competitors` before the new migrations??

Comment: any, i added after the migrations

Answer (score 0):

You didn't stablish `alter_comp_id`to be `nullable`, and later you try to create a row with that column null. So... Either specify that value

```
$ci->alternativecompetitors()->associate($keyCanvas);
```

, or re-migrate the table to allow that field to be null, like this:

```
$table->integer('alter_comp_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```